# How to extract Array from JSON in $.ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a json value converted from array in ajax response.

```
{"Text":"Please provide a value","Email":"Please provide a value"}
```

I need the response json to be extracted in a div using $(div).html():

```
Text-Please provide a value
Email-Please provide a value
```

I tried it using $.each():

```
var json=JSON.stringify({"Text":"Please provide a value","Email":"Please provide a value"});
    var arr = [];
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
    $.each(json,function(key,value)
    {
     arr.push('<li>'+value+'</li>');
    });
    var arrval =arr.join('');
    console.log(arrval);
```

But I got output as undefined. I know there is some logical mistake I have done while extracting? What have I done wrong in here??

Note: The array key value pair in json can be dynamic ie., it may be one, two or more..

Comment: You are iterating over the original string. You should write `$.each(obj, ...)` instead of `$.each(json, ...)`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks for showing correct way. Your suggestion worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be helpful

```
var  json = {"Text":"Please provide a value","Email":"Please provide a value"};
var arr = [];
$.each(json,function(key,value){
    arr.push('<li>'+value+'</li>');
});
var arrval =arr.join('');
console.log(arrval);
```

Comment: I thought calling $.parseJSON() on json (json to object conversion) and then $.makeArray() on the result (object to array conversion)  would get me the array I wanted, but my $.parseJSON() resulted a  null. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

see this if it helps !!

```
var jsonData = {"Text":"Please provide a value","Email":"Please provide a value"};
var arr = [];
for(var j in jsonData){
    var sub_key = j;
    var sub_val = eval("jsonData."+j);
    arr.push('<li>'+sub_key+": "+sub_val+'</li>');    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(obj).each(function(index,value)
{
  arr.push('<li>'+value.Text+'</li>');
});
```

your json have to look like:

```
[{"Text":"Please provide a value","Email":"Please provide a value"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

json is an array of objects, thus has a length property that you can use to iterate its elements.

```
var result;

for(var i=0;i<json.data.length;i++)
{
      result += json.data[i].text+ ', ';
}
```

Most debugger consoles support displaying objects directly. Just check your result using

```
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: How exactly does that fit the question? Please edit to improve.